# IceFaces javascript won't works in a liferay portlet

Tags: javascript, liferay, portlet, icefaces-1.8, no-op

I deployed an application (made with ice faces 1.8) that works on Liferay5 in a weblogic into a Liferay6 with tomcat. The application and everything seems good....the only thing that won't works is the javascript...when i click on a button, change a select, when an ajax call should be made nothing is made. I debbugged a little bit the javascript and see that in the function *iceSubmit* and *iceSubmitPartial* there is the call to the method *H.sendOn(currentConnection($element(B), $element(D)));*

and this method is implemented as follows:

```
sendOn: function(B) {
            B.send(this);
        }
```

and the method *send* for the object passed (an HtmlDiv) is implemented with the noop function:

```
Function.NOOP = function() {
};
```

The question is...why can happens this???
I don't know JSF and sincerely I don't know where I can start to search something...

Answer (score 0):

http://www.liferay.com/web/nathan.cavanaugh/blog/-/blogs/using-jquery-or-any-javascript-library-in-liferay-6-0

I had a similar issue upgrading to Liferay 6. After modifying the theme to load all the javascript files in portal_normal.vm, some of the broken functionality got restored (in my case it was jQuery).